# Simple TCP connect timeout wrapper in Delphi

Tags: multithreading, delphi, sockets, tcp, winsock

I'm trying to create a `connect` wrapper which supports a timeout parameter.

The main function should look like this:

```
function ConnectToHost (Host : PAnsiChar; Port : Word; Timeout: DWORD): Integer;
```

---

I would like too keep it as simple as possible and keep the sockets in blocking mode.

Also, the idea is to use pure Winsock API and no Indy components or anything.

---

The main function should return an Integer for additional infos about what happened.

I was thinking about return values that are mostly returned by the `connect` function and additional values for timeout information.

---

Inside the main function there is a thread that takes care of the connection while the main function waits for the thread for the given timeout.

---

Now I am worried about passing the data such as Host and Port to the thread and Memory Leaks.

I'm thinking about using these APIs for the timeout operation:

- `CreateThread`
- `WaitForSingleObject`
- `GetExitCodeThread`
- `TerminateThread`?

and these APIs for the TCP connection using winsock:

- `socket`
- `htons`
- `inet_addr`
- `connect`

How could a safe `connect` wrapper look like with a timeout consideration?

Right now I seem not to know how I can accomplish this. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Indy implements a threaded connect timeout.  You could look to see how it does it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
type
  PConnectInfo = ^ConnectInfo;
  ConnectInfo = record
    Socket: TSocket;
    Addr: sockaddr_in;
    ErrCode: Integer;
  end;

function ConnectProc(Param : Pointer): DWORD; stdcall;
begin
  With PConnectInfo(Param)^ do
  begin
    if connect(Socket, PAddrInfo(@Addr), SizeOf(Addr)) = 0 then
      ErrCode := 0
    else
      ErrCode := WSAGetLastError;
  end;
  Result := 0;
end;

function ConnectToHost (Host : PAnsiChar; Port : Word; Timeout: DWORD): Integer;
var
  ci: ConnectInfo;
  H: THandle;
  tid: DWORD;
begin
  Result := 0;

  ZeroMemory(@ci, SizeOf(ci));

  ci.Socket := ...;

  ZeroMemory(@ci, SizeOf(ci));
  ci.Addr.sin_family := AF_INET;
  ci.Addr.sin_addr.s_addr := inet_addr(Host);
  ci.Addr.sin_port := htons(Port);

  if Timeout = INFINITE then
  begin
    ConnectProc(@ci);
  end else
  begin
    h := CreateThread(nil, 0, @ConnectProc, @ci, 0, @tid);
    if h = 0 then
    begin
      Result := GetLastError;
      Exit;
    end;

    case WaitForSingleObject(h, Timeout) of
      WAIT_FAILED: begin
        Result := GetLastError;
      end;
      WAIT_OBJECT_0: begin
        Result := ci.ErrCode;
      end;
      WAIT_TIMEOUT: begin
        Result := WSAETIMEDOUT;
      end;
    else
      Result := -1;
    end;

    CloseHandle(h);
  end;

  if Result <> 0 then
    closesocket(ci.Socket);
end;
```

Comment: Perfect! Thank you. This is even more advanced than I had in mind.

Comment: Though is it valid to call `closesocket` while `connect` is still active?

Comment: Yes, it is valid, and is the only way to abort a blocking connect.

Comment: Would `TerminateThread` be an alternative to abort `connect`?

Comment: Stay away from `TerminateThread()`.  Brute-force terminating a thread leaves its resources in an indeterminate state. And you might mess up the socket's internals. Best to just use `closesocket()`, which will abort `connect()` with a detectable error and let the thread exit gracefully.